# (multiple) fractional outcomes & autoregression

Tags: bayesian, forecasting, autoregressive, vector-autoregression, many-categories

Let me start with a broad description of the problem and I will then describe my approach (that might be totally inappropiate).
The big goal is to predict the distribution of population of a given age (say 15-24) across "educational states" e.g. undergrad in humanities, undergrad social sciences, high-school student, vocational school pupil in IT etc. (I define ~ 20 such states). I have a 20 years long time series of a small, but representative sample from the population.

My approach is to:

- calculate the ratios of states in the sample (that neccessarily sum up to one),
- *somehow* examine how those ratios evolve over time (problem: time-series is short)
- predict the ratios for the next few years
- multiply the ratios by the expected total population size

Apart from obvious problem with the sample siize and time-series length, how would I approach a question of trends in fractional outcomes? Since I have little intuition on what exogenous variables would explain the changes, I wanted to start with an autoregressive model. But does it make sense here? And how to include the restriction that the ratios must be postive and sum up to 1 in every prediction?

(edit) I was suggested to use Bayesian VAR - how sensible it is?
(further edit) After a long search and consideration, my current approach is as follows:
- transform ratios into log-odds (with logit function)
- use Bayesian VAR with Banbura prior to forecast (as it looks robust and consistent with a stylized fact that education choices do not change rapidly)
- transform back with inverse-logit to ratios.

My questions: does it make sense? What assumptions about the data I implictly employ? What do I need to check (some statistical tests?) to make sure this approach is valid?

Comment: Can you clarify your objective? Distribution for a given age across... 20 years? How will you put all this together?

Comment: The objective is to model (and predict) changes in the students' degree choices, e.g. to check whether graduate studies in humanities are becoming more or less popular over time (given the alternatives).
Update: I currently sketched a version in which I transform ratios to log-odds, then perform a Bayesian VAR with very simple (Banbura) prior and re-transfrom the prediction into ratios again. However, the relevant question is how sensible/robust/statistically correct it is.

Comment: `check whether graduate studies in humanities are becoming more or less popular over time` This sounds like it could be done with a linear model? Would that be an option?

Comment: Sure. The problem with "normal" linear model is that my learning sample is much smaller then the actual population that I am trying to forecast. That's why I switched to fractions, under the assumption that the fraction of "graduates in humanisties" would be the same in the sample and in the population.

Comment: OK, so you converted your values into fractions to deal with relative values instead of absolute ones. i still don't understand why a linear model is not appropriate. What do you mean your "learning" sample is much smaller then the population? That you have a very small sample? If so then no method is going to solve for a lack of information.

Comment: The sample I use is not bad - in total, circa 300k observation a year. I am trying to forecast the population of 20 mln. The lack of information is not an issue.

Comment: A linear model is fine for me (the simpler the better), as long as it works well with fractions. With a standard OLS and fractions it's quite easy, unfortunately, to reach predictions that violate restrictions, i.e. fraction<0, fraction>1 or sum of fractions different than 1.

Comment: If you are worried that since your DV is a fraction (and so bounded) this will cause problems with a regular linear model, then you can use beta regression, which is used when your DV is bounded in $(0,1)$. An easy transformation of your data can transform from $[0,1]$ to $(0,1)$.

Comment: As for now (see update of the question) I use logit to transform the data, but beta could be fine as well. What are the advantages of one vs. another? Btw, VAR (my current approach) is a linear model.

Comment: If your DV is bounded and you have a lot of values on the boundaries then a logit transformation will not save you, the assumptions of the model are not satisfied and you will get wrong values for SE, CI, p-values,...

Comment: Ok, thanks. Nothing is close the upper bound (i.e. to 1), but indeed, a few proportions are very close to 0. So is there something like beta-VAR? VAR has a nice interpretation here, as my intuition is that the process is highly persistent with only minor adjustment (e.g. some people choosing social science instead of humanities) that I want to capture in time.

Comment: I don't think it exists. The closest thing I found is this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/232697/beta-regression-accounting-for-residual-spatial-auto-correlation-in-r

Comment: Wow, this looks more complicated than I thought... Thanks for the reference!